# Creating unique way of column value from collect_set

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

When use `collect_set` in aggregate function I get `[]` for `None` values but I want like `[None]` typically like Array values in pyspark. Is there any way to replace it? For Non-None values it looks ok already.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] with sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 'A'), (2, None), (1, None), (3, 'B')], ['col1', 'col2'])
df = df.fillna('None')
display(df.groupBy('col1').agg(f.collect_set('col2').alias('setCol2')))
```